# Bar in Bar Chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to plot bar in bar chart in R with ggplot2 like the figure below. I want to compare expected and actual values and I want to generate a figure similar to the figure below. I have provided some dummy code:

```
 library(tidyverse)

df = data_frame(name = letters[1:10],profit = rnorm(mean = 100, sd = 20, n = 10),
            target = profit + rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 10, n = 10))

   df %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = profit)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186060/overlay-two-bar-plots-with-geom-bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, look at ggplot documentation

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data_frame(name = letters[1:10],profit = rnorm(mean = 100, sd = 20, n = 10),
                target = profit + rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 10, n = 10))

ggplot(df,aes(x=name,y=profit))+geom_bar(stat= "identity")+
geom_bar(aes(x= name,y=target),stat= "identity", width = 0.1,col = "green",fill="green")
```